# CAPTCHA Validation

Tags: captcha

I've created a custom validation script for my website because people need to validate every hour to make sure they aren't using scripts/auto-refreshers to gain an advantage.  To make the experience as easy as possible, an image is displayed with a number between 1 and 9.  I created all these images manually with photoshop to make them slightly difficult to see.  The user must then click a randomised "numpad" between 1 and 9 with the right number which is displayed below this first image.

My question is as follows:

How easy is it for someone to write a script/program of some-kind that can read the source-code, check the name of the div that displays the image with the number and then read the file-name to see what the image name is and then use an OCR to click the right number on the chart?

I have absolutely no idea how I would even start doing this, but I want to know if it's necessary to change the image filename to something random every time, rather than something like number1.png, number2.png etc

Many thanks in advance for your help and advice

Comment: I'm sure there are plenty of implementations available already which you can use by free. Why waste your time trying to invent the wheel...again?

Comment: I have searched many times and there just isn't a captcha available that suits my needs perfectly.  They all involve the user having to waste too much time.  The validation should be fast and easy, not complicated and time-wasting.  That's why I am creating a custom validation script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it would be really TOO easy!

1. it's really too easy to read the divs names!
2. yes, you should change images name each time
3. if the images are only 9, the attacker   can play some hours, save all the different images, and then he won't even need OCR because he will only compare the images pixel by pixel!

Comment: I had considered creating the images dynamically and making them all different, but this proved extremely difficult to do with the php functions (I got rather confused).

Out of curiosity, how on earth does someone write something to read divs/save images and compare pixel to pixel?  I wouldn't even know where to start, so I'd like to understand the method so I can improve my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Static images are simply not CAPTCHA, as a user could map each static file to a number and bypass your mechanism.

Comment: How would the person go about doing this?  I am interested to learn how someone would do it + what they would even use to do it.  I understand that static images are not CAPTCHAs but I ran into a few difficulties with the image creation in PHP so I made a quick-fix solution which I can improve with the dynamic image generation in the near future.

Comment: A malicious user could search for a unique value for each image (like a computed hash value, file size, etc.) and map this unique value to the number it represents thus allowing a simple bypass to your pseudo-CAPTCHA system

Answer (score 0):

You should create images dynamically with random numbers and random names. Store the number somewhere (mostly in session variables) and match the user input with that value.

Comment: As Jeroen mentioned there are third party pluggins available for the same which you can use.

Comment: As stated in the other comment, I wanted to create the images dynamically but it proved difficult with the php draw (i think) and it was all a little overwhelming.  I guess I will have to go back and think about that again..